# Parse(DB with relationships) + Firebase(Realtime)

Tags: parse-platform, firebase

Is there some service out there like Parse/Firebase that supports DB with relationships and realtime applications?

I was looking to use Parse since it has strong support for DB with many relationships, but I missed the realtime listener-observer pattern from firebase.

I would be the best if I could keep using Parse but the realtime listener-observer pattern could be added to my application easily.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use both? Parse to store data and Firebase for listener-observer (KVO etc) needs? You may also want to consider Firebase alone; listener-observer patterns are the core of Firebase. We have found Firebase to be quite capable of handling many database needs  and can even be leveraged to handle relationships (in a Firebase way) and other data storage. We are Parse fans as well but the lack of real-time communication often steers us back to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks Jay, could you please describe briefly the difference of Firebase and Parse when it comes to data class relationships?

Comment: Not sure I have enough characters! Keep in mind that Firebase it not relational, you have to code that way. It doesn't support random objects directly, but supports the back end data that objects need to work together. Take a department and employees example: The dept object loads its properties from Firebase: name, location, and which employees it has. Likewise, employee objects know their name, and which department they belong to. The beauty of Firebase is that if an employee changes departments (is removed, added) other employees can be instantly notified of the change.

Comment: Parse and Firebase store data in a similar way on the back end (JSON) but the way you get at that data is different. Parse objects can be inherited and relationships can be crafted through objects like Pointers and Relations. If I were building a complex, multi-relational database, like an accounting system, it would probably be less code/easier in Parse. However, because Firebase has real-time observers, when a user generates an invoice when a product is sold, the inventory is updated live and all other clients are immediately notified - Parse doesn't really do that (they suggest polling?)